# What is the difference in "find_element_by_xpath" and "driver.find_elements(By.XPATH)"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been using selenium for a while with these two methods interchangeably.

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("some_xpath")
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"some_xpath")
```

So far both of them work. I wanted to understand what is the difference in both of them.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html Documentation mentions By.XPATH as private method, but did not understand it clearly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`find_element_by_xpath('xpath')` calls `find_element(By.XPATH,'xpath')`, so actually there is no real difference.

From [github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py)

```
def find_element_by_xpath(self, xpath):
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
```

As of Selenium 4.3, the find_element_by_* and find_elements_by_* methods are deprecated. See the [Selenium change log](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/bcbf432b6b0d47084f46f1009b0241908f1f28e3/py/CHANGES).