# How to Scroll down a Dialog box with Selenium + Python

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have a dialog box from a medical web app which shows only 30 patients in the first screen, to view more pacients i have scroll down the dialog box and when i close to the thirtieth pacient it shows 30 more.

I'm trying to show more than 2000 paciente on that dialog box while I'm opening in a new window their link profile and collecting info and saving in a xmls file.

How can I scroll down using Python + Selenium?

This is the dialog box screen:

[image: Dialog Box]

This html is the dialog box with the 6 first firsts patients and 
thirtieth, I couldn't post all the 30 (character limit):

```html
<md-dialog aria-label="Pacientes" ng-form="mainForm" flex="70" flex-xl="40" class="ng-pristine ng-valid _md flex-xl-40 flex-70 md-transition-in" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-describedby="dialogContent_573" style="">
    <md-toolbar md-theme="white" class="_md md-white-theme _md-toolbar-transitions">
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools layout-wrap layout-row" layout="row" layout-wrap="">
            <h2 flex="100" flex-gt-xs="50" class="flex-gt-xs-50 flex-100">Pacientes</h2>
            <md-input-container flex="100" flex-gt-xs="50" md-no-float="" style="padding: 0;" class="md-input-has-placeholder md-white-theme flex-gt-xs-50 flex-100">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Pesquisar" ng-model="pacienteCtrl.search" ng-change="pacienteCtrl.onChangeSearch()" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid md-input ng-empty" id="input_572" aria-invalid="false" style=""><div class="md-errors-spacer"></div>
            </md-input-container>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>

    <md-dialog-content class="md-dialog-content" when-scrolled="pacienteCtrl.nextPage()" id="dialogContent_573">
        <div layout="column" class="layout-column">
            <md-divider></md-divider>
            <md-list class="sd-list-pacientes" role="list">
                <!----><md-list-item class="md-2-line md-no-proxy _md" ng-repeat="paciente in pacienteCtrl.pacientes" paciente-link="" paciente="paciente" role="listitem" style="">
                    <img ng-src="assets/img/user-default.png" class="md-avatar" src="assets/img/user-default.png">
                    <div layout="column" class="md-list-item-text layout-column">
                        <a ng-click="go()" class="sd-link" paciente="paciente" aria-label="Ir para a ficha desse paciente" md-labeled-by-tooltip="md-tooltip-574" ng-href="https://app.simplesdental.com/simples/pacientes/11489833/sobre" href="https://app.simplesdental.com/simples/pacientes/11489833/sobre">
    
    Abraão Laurentino dos Santos
   </a>
                        <div layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row" class="sd-list-pacientes-info layout-gt-sm-row layout-column">
                            <!---->
                            <!----><span class="sd-list-pacientes-info-item" ng-if="paciente.celular">
                                <md-icon md-svg-icon="phone" role="img" aria-label="phone"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fit="" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false"><path d="M31 2H15c-2.76 0-5 2.24-5 5v34c0 2.76 2.24 5 5 5h16c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5V7c0-2.76-2.24-5-5-5zm-8 42c-1.66 0-3-1.34-3-3s1.34-3 3-3 3 1.34 3 3-1.34 3-3 3zm9-8H14V8h18v28z"></path></svg></md-icon>
                                <span class="grey">(xx) xxxxx-xxxx</span>
                            </span><!---->
                            <!---->
                            <!----><span class="sd-list-pacientes-info-item" ng-if="paciente.cpf">
                                <md-icon md-svg-icon="person" role="img" aria-label="person"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fit="" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false"><path d="M24 24c4.42 0 8-3.59 8-8 0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8s-8 3.58-8 8c0 4.41 3.58 8 8 8zm0 4c-5.33 0-16 2.67-16 8v4h32v-4c0-5.33-10.67-8-16-8z"></path></svg></md-icon>
                                <span class="grey">xxx.xxx.xxx-xx</span>
                            </span><!---->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <md-divider></md-divider>
                <div class="md-secondary-container"></div></md-list-item><!----><md-list-item class="md-2-line md-no-proxy _md" ng-repeat="paciente in pacienteCtrl.pacientes" paciente-link="" paciente="paciente" role="listitem">
                    <img ng-src="assets/img/user-default.png" class="md-avatar" src="assets/img/user-default.png">
                    <div layout="column" class="md-list-item-text layout-column">
                        <a ng-click="go()" class="sd-link" paciente="paciente" aria-label="Ir para a ficha desse paciente" md-labeled-by-tooltip="md-tooltip-575" ng-href="https://app.simplesdental.com/simples/pacientes/11827315/sobre" href="https://app.simplesdental.com/simples/pacientes/11827315/sobre">
    
    Acyr Xavier Moreira
   </a>
                        <div layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row" class="sd-list-pacientes-info layout-gt-sm-row layout-column">
                            <!---->
                            <!----><span class="sd-list-pacientes-info-item" ng-if="paciente.celular">
                                <md-icon md-svg-icon="phone" role="img" aria-label="phone"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fit="" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false"><path d="M31 2H15c-2.76 0-5 2.24-5 5v34c0 2.76 2.24 5 5 5h16c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5V7c0-2.76-2.24-5-5-5zm-8 42c-1.66 0-3-1.34-3-3s1.34-3 3-3 3 1.34 3 3-1.34 3-3 3zm9-8H14V8h18v28z"></path></svg></md-icon>
                                <span class="grey">(xx) xxxxx-xxxx</span>
                            </span><!---->
                            <!---->
                            <!----><span class="sd-list-pacientes-info-item" ng-if="paciente.cpf">
                                <md-icon md-svg-icon="person" role="img" aria-label="person"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fit="" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false"><path d="M24 24c4.42 0 8-3.59 8-8 0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8s-8 3.58-8 8c0 4.41 3.58 8 8 8zm0 4c-5.33 0-16 2.67-16 8v4h32v-4c0-5.33-10.67-8-16-8z"></path></svg></md-icon>
                                <span class="grey">xxx.xxx.xxx-xx</span>
                            </span><!---->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <md-divider></md-divider>
                <div class="md-secondary-container"></div></md-list-item><!----><md-list-item class="md-2-line md-no-proxy _md" ng-repeat="paciente in pacienteCtrl.pacientes" paciente-link="" paciente="paciente" role="listitem">
                    <img ng-src="assets/img/user-default.png" class="md-avatar" src="assets/img/user-default.png">
                    <div layout="column" class="md-list-item-text layout-column">
                        <a ng-click="go()" class="sd-link" paciente="paciente" aria-label="Ir para a ficha desse paciente" md-labeled-by-tooltip="md-tooltip-576" ng-href="https://app.simplesdental.com/simples/pacientes/17258954/sobre" href="https://app.simplesdental.com/simples/pacientes/17258954/sobre">
    
    Adilton Junior
   </a>
                        <div layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row" class="sd-list-pacientes-info layout-gt-sm-row layout-column">
                            <!---->
                            <!----><span class="sd-list-pacientes-info-item" ng-if="paciente.celular">
                                <md-icon md-svg-icon="phone" role="img" aria-label="phone"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fit="" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false"><path d="M31 2H15c-2.76 0-5 2.24-5 5v34c0 2.76 2.24 5 5 5h16c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5V7c0-2.76-2.24-5-5-5zm-8 42c-1.66 0-3-1.34-3-3s1.34-3 3-3 3 1.34 3 3-1.34 3-3 3zm9-8H14V8h18v28z"></path></svg></md-icon>
                                <span class="grey">(xx) xxxxx-xxxx</span>
                            </span><!---->
                            <!---->
                            <!----><span class="sd-list-pacientes-info-item" ng-if="paciente.cpf">
                                <md-icon md-svg-icon="person" role="img" aria-label="person"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fit="" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false"><path d="M24 24c4.42 0 8-3.59 8-8 0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8s-8 3.58-8 8c0 4.41 3.58 8 8 8zm0 4c-5.33 0-16 2.67-16 8v4h32v-4c0-5.33-10.67-8-16-8z"></path></svg></md-icon>
                                <span class="grey">xxx.xxx.xxx-xx</span>
                            </span><!---->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <md-divider></md-divider>
                <div class="md-secondary-container"></div></md-list-item><!----><md-list-item class="md-2-line md-no-proxy _md" ng-repeat="paciente in pacienteCtrl.pacientes" paciente-link="" paciente="paciente" role="listitem">
                    <img ng-src="assets/img/user-default.png" class="md-avatar" src="assets/img/user-default.png">
                    <div layout="column" class="md-list-item-text layout-column">
                        <a ng-click="go()" class="sd-link" paciente="paciente" aria-label="Ir para a ficha desse paciente" md-labeled-by-tooltip="md-tooltip-577" ng-href="https://app.simplesdental.com/simples/pacientes/15922853/sobre" href="https://app.simplesdental.com/simples/pacientes/15922853/sobre">
    
    Adalberto Cortes da Silva
   </a>
                        <div layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row" class="sd-list-pacientes-info layout-gt-sm-row layout-column">
                            <!---->
                            <!----><span class="sd-list-pacientes-info-item" ng-if="paciente.celular">
                                <md-icon md-svg-icon="phone" role="img" aria-label="phone"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fit="" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false"><path d="M31 2H15c-2.76 0-5 2.24-5 5v34c0 2.76 2.24 5 5 5h16c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5V7c0-2.76-2.24-5-5-5zm-8 42c-1.66 0-3-1.34-3-3s1.34-3 3-3 3 1.34 3 3-1.34 3-3 3zm9-8H14V8h18v28z"></path></svg></md-icon>
                                <span class="grey">(xx) xxxxx-xxxx</span>
                            </span><!---->
                            <!---->
                            <!----><span class="sd-list-pacientes-info-item" ng-if="paciente.cpf">
                                <md-icon md-svg-icon="person" role="img" aria-label="person"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fit="" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false"><path d="M24 24c4.42 0 8-3.59 8-8 0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8s-8 3.58-8 8c0 4.41 3.58 8 8 8zm0 4c-5.33 0-16 2.67-16 8v4h32v-4c0-5.33-10.67-8-16-8z"></path></svg></md-icon>
                                <span class="grey">xxx.xxx.xxx-xx</span>
                            </span><!---->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <md-divider></md-divider>
                <div class="md-secondary-container"></div></md-list-item><!----><md-list-item class="md-2-line md-no-proxy _md" ng-repeat="paciente in pacienteCtrl.pacientes" paciente-link="" paciente="paciente" role="listitem">
                    <img ng-src="assets/img/user-default.png" class="md-avatar" src="assets/img/user-default.png">
                    <div layout="column" class="md-list-item-text layout-column">
                        <a ng-click="go()" class="sd-link" paciente="paciente" aria-label="Ir para a ficha desse paciente" md-labeled-by-tooltip="md-tooltip-578" ng-href="https://app.simplesdental.com/simples/pacientes/13516998/sobre" href="https://app.simplesdental.com/simples/pacientes/13516998/sobre">
    
    Adalton Barbosa Cardoso Cunha
   </a>
                        <div layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row" class="sd-list-pacientes-info layout-gt-sm-row layout-column">
                            <!---->
                            <!----><span class="sd-list-pacientes-info-item" ng-if="paciente.celular">
                                <md-icon md-svg-icon="phone" role="img" aria-label="phone"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fit="" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false"><path d="M31 2H15c-2.76 0-5 2.24-5 5v34c0 2.76 2.24 5 5 5h16c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5V7c0-2.76-2.24-5-5-5zm-8 42c-1.66 0-3-1.34-3-3s1.34-3 3-3 3 1.34 3 3-1.34 3-3 3zm9-8H14V8h18v28z"></path></svg></md-icon>
                                <span class="grey">(xx) xxxxx-xxxx</span>
                            </span><!---->
                            <!---->
                            <!----><span class="sd-list-pacientes-info-item" ng-if="paciente.cpf">
                                <md-icon md-svg-icon="person" role="img" aria-label="person"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fit="" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false"><path d="M24 24c4.42 0 8-3.59 8-8 0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8s-8 3.58-8 8c0 4.41 3.58 8 8 8zm0 4c-5.33 0-16 2.67-16 8v4h32v-4c0-5.33-10.67-8-16-8z"></path></svg></md-icon>
                                <span class="grey">xxx.xxx.xxx-xx</span>
                            </span><!---->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <md-divider></md-divider>
                <div class="md-secondary-container"></div></md-list-item><!----><md-list-item class="md-2-line md-no-proxy _md" ng-repeat="paciente in pacienteCtrl.pacientes" paciente-link="" paciente="paciente" role="listitem">
                    <img ng-src="assets/img/user-default.png" class="md-avatar" src="assets/img/user-default.png">
                    <div layout="column" class="md-list-item-text layout-column">
                        <a ng-click="go()" class="sd-link" paciente="paciente" aria-label="Ir para a ficha desse paciente" md-labeled-by-tooltip="md-tooltip-579" ng-href="https://app.simplesdental.com/simples/pacientes/17103848/sobre" href="https://app.simplesdental.com/simples/pacientes/17103848/sobre">
    
    Adelina de Oliveira
   </a>
                        <div layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row" class="sd-list-pacientes-info layout-gt-sm-row layout-column">
                            <!---->
                            <!----><span class="sd-list-pacientes-info-item" ng-if="paciente.celular">
                                <md-icon md-svg-icon="phone" role="img" aria-label="phone"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fit="" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false"><path d="M31 2H15c-2.76 0-5 2.24-5 5v34c0 2.76 2.24 5 5 5h16c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5V7c0-2.76-2.24-5-5-5zm-8 42c-1.66 0-3-1.34-3-3s1.34-3 3-3 3 1.34 3 3-1.34 3-3 3zm9-8H14V8h18v28z"></path></svg></md-icon>
                                <span class="grey">(xx) xxxxx-xxxx</span>
                            </span><!---->
                            <!---->
                            <!---->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <md-divider></md-divider>
                <div class="md-secondary-container"></div></md-list-item><!----><md-list-item class="md-2-line md-no-proxy _md" ng-repeat="paciente in pacienteCtrl.pacientes" paciente-link="" paciente="paciente" role="listitem">
                    <img ng-src="assets/img/user-default.png" class="md-avatar" src="assets/img/user-default.png">
                    <div layout="column" class="md-list-item-text layout-column">
                        <a ng-click="go()" class="sd-link" paciente="paciente" aria-label="Ir para a ficha desse paciente" md-labeled-by-tooltip="md-tooltip-580" ng-href="https://app.simplesdental.com/simples/pacientes/12563381/sobre" href="https://app.simplesdental.com/simples/pacientes/12563381/sobre">
    
    Alan Albuquerque
   </a>
                        <div layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row" class="sd-list-pacientes-info layout-gt-sm-row layout-column">
                            <!---->
                            <!----><span class="sd-list-pacientes-info-item" ng-if="paciente.celular">
                                <md-icon md-svg-icon="phone" role="img" aria-label="phone"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fit="" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false"><path d="M31 2H15c-2.76 0-5 2.24-5 5v34c0 2.76 2.24 5 5 5h16c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5V7c0-2.76-2.24-5-5-5zm-8 42c-1.66 0-3-1.34-3-3s1.34-3 3-3 3 1.34 3 3-1.34 3-3 3zm9-8H14V8h18v28z"></path></svg></md-icon>
                                <span class="grey">(xx) xxxxx-xxxx</span>
                            </span><!---->
                            <!---->
                            <!---->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <md-divider></md-divider>
                <div class="md-secondary-container"></div></md-list-item><!---->
            </md-list>
        </div>
        <div layout="column" ng-show="!pacienteCtrl.pacientes.length" layout-align="center center" class="layout-align-center-center layout-column ng-hide" aria-hidden="true" style="">
            <p class="inset">Sem resultados para a busca</p>
        </div>
    </md-dialog-content>

    <md-dialog-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center" class="layout-align-end-center layout-row">
        <button class="md-button md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="pacienteCtrl.closeDialog()"> Fechar </button>
    </md-dialog-actions>
</md-dialog>
```

This is my code where i'm tryong to scroll down:

> element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//div[@class='md-dialog-container']//md-list-item[30]"))#Select last child of content div
>   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element) #Scroll to last child node

But I'm receving the message error:

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//div[@class='md-dialog-container']//md-list-item[30]")) #Select last child of content div
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

...implies that your program have invoked a `function()` which is actually a `property`.

As per Selenium [doc](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element) this is the right method signature:

> `find_element(by='id', value=None)`
>
> ```
> Find an element given a By strategy and locator. Prefer the find_element_by_* methods when possible.
> Usage :   element = element.find_element(By.ID, ‘foo’)
> Return type:  WebElement
> ```

And this is mentioned in doc

> ```
> def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):
>     """
>     Find an element given a By strategy and locator. Prefer the find_element_by_* methods when
>     possible.
>
>     :Usage:
>         element = element.find_element(By.ID, 'foo')
>
>     :rtype: WebElement
>     """
>     if self._w3c:
>         if by == By.ID:
>             by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
>             value = '[id="%s"]' % value
>         elif by == By.TAG_NAME:
>             by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
>         elif by == By.CLASS_NAME:
>             by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
>             value = ".%s" % value
>         elif by == By.NAME:
>             by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
>             value = '[name="%s"]' % value
>
>     return self._execute(Command.FIND_CHILD_ELEMENT,
>                          {"using": by, "value": value})['value']
> ```

So as per method signature you should use either

```
last_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='md-dialog-container']//md-list-item[30]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", last_element)
```

OR

```
last_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='md-dialog-container']//md-list-item[30]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", last_element)
```

Comment: Thanks for it. I couldn't look this function.

So as the Doc says is it better to use by_xpath than By.XPATH? It really makes difference? What is the gain for the program?

Comment: @MarquesDev this is answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55467209/what-is-the-difference-in-find-element-by-xpath-and-driver-find-elementsby-x